# type linklist while causing invalid redefinition of constant

Tags: julia

```
type nListNode{T}  

child::nListNode{T}  

nListNode()=(l=new();l.child=l)  

end
```

What's the wrong with my grammer that causes the redefinition???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redifinition error is probably because you already defined `nListNode` sometime earlier in the Julia session (so just restart Julia). Additionally, here are some more suggestions:

- Make sure you are using the newer version >=0.6 of Julia, as the old syntax will be going away.
- In the new syntax `mutable struct` replaces `type`.

Then, the following should work:

```
mutable struct nListNode{T}
    child::nListNode{T}
    nListNode{T}() where T = (l = new(); l.child = l; l)
end
```

But, don't you want to include an element with type `T` in the structure?

Comment: it works,thanks! at the end of 3rd code line,is the single l unnecessary?

Comment: Not necessary, but it's like a comment - makes things clearer and doesn't cost anything (trivially understood by compiler)